# Multiple inheritance MRO

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class Class1: 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class1") 
  
class Class2(Class1): 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class2") 
        super().m() 
  
class Class3(Class1): 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class3") 
        super().m() 
  
class Class4(Class2, Class3): 
    def m(self): 
        print("In Class4")    
        super().m() 
       
obj = Class4() 
obj.m()
```

The output is :

```
In Class4
In Class2
In Class3
In Class1
```

MRO is `[__main__.Class4, __main__.Class2, __main__.Class3, __main__.Class1, object]`

When `obj.m()` is called it prints `In Class4` and then calls the method `m()` of base classes going left to right. When `m()` is called for `Class2`, it also has `super.m()` then why is `Class1` `m()` method not called first before `Class3` `m()` method ? `Class2` `m()` method should finish executing completely (`super.m()` should execute in the function of `Class2()`) before `m()` is called for next base class (i.e. `Class3`)

Comment: "then why is Class1 m() method not called first before Class3 m()" because Class3 comes first in the method resolution order?

Comment: "Class2 m() method should finish executing completely (super.m() should execute in the function of Class2()) before m() is called for next base class (i.e. Class3)" huh? Why do you think that? The first method that completes is actually `Class1`... but that's just how functions work (understanding the call stack...) that doesn't really have anything to do with multiple inheritance... I'm not really sure if I understand your question

Comment: "super" is poorly named because it does not indicate the superclass.  Python's implementation was more or less lifted from another programming language ([Dylan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_(programming_language))), where super was named "next-method".